# Не получается выполнить авторизацию через smtplib

Tags: python, smtp

Не могу выполнить аутентификацию на сервере, используя конфиг файл, чтобы убрать из скрипта логин/пароль.
Получаю ошибку:

> raise SMTPException("No suitable authentication method found.")
>   smtplib.SMTPException: No suitable authentication method found.

```
import smtplib
import os
import sys
from configparser import ConfigParser
def send_mail(subject, body_text):  
    # Send an email

    base_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    config_path = os.path.join(base_path, 'email_config.ini')

    if os.path.exists(config_path):
        cfg = ConfigParser()        
        cfg.read(config_path)       
    else:
        print("Config not found! Exiting!")
        sys.exit(0)

    host = cfg.get('smtp', 'server')
    from_addr = cfg.get('smtp', 'from_addr')
    to_addr = cfg.get('smtp', 'to_addr')
    copy_reciever = cfg.get('smtp', 'copy_reciever')
    username = cfg.get('smtp', 'username')
    password = cfg.get('smtp', 'password')


    body = "\r\n".join((
        "From: {0}".format(from_addr),
        "To: {0}".format(to_addr),
        "Subject: {0}".format(subject),
        "CC: {0}".format(copy_reciever),
        "",
        body_text
        ))
    server = smtplib.SMTP(host)
    server.login(username, password)    
    server.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr, body.encode('utf-8'))
    server.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    subject = 'Headline!'       
    body_text = "text of email" 
    send_mail(subject, body_text)
```

Comment: server.login('username', 'password') кавычки убери

Comment: Тот же самый результат.

Comment: Отправка идет через Exchange, если это имеет значение.

Comment: Если он не правильно настроен

Comment: Необходимо было указать порт при подключении.
server = smtplib.SMTP(host, 587)